# How to send data from sqlite to server?

Tags: android, sqlite, wcf, android-volley

Here am using volley for making network transaction am tying to convert the value from sqlite to json using gson library am trying to connect with wcf service but am getting unexpected reponse 400 my url will be like this localhost/service.svc/{param} in this i need pass the value here i got struck into this how to resolve this here let me post my code:

```
 listobj=account_sf_db.toServer();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String param=gson.toJson(listobj);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


    /*    final String god=listobj.toString();
        JSONObject yogan=new JSONObject();
int i=0;
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
        try {
            for (Model_Account modlobj:listobj){
                JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();
                jobj.put("yog", modlobj.getState());

              jsonArray.put(i,jobj);
            }
yogan.put("yoges",jsonArray);

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        final  String gods="yoga:";
        final String URL="http://xx.xx.x.xx/xxx/xx/xxx.svc/Account/xx/"+param;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String god = error.toString();

            }
        }){



            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders ()throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;

            }


        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
```

Comment: You can create Json Object/array with Gson and send your json object or array to post with volley as well if you want to send single filed than you can send directly as string param.

Comment: can you share some snippet ajay